# How to add a custom field to the projections in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring project which has the following interface.

```java
interface TaskIdAndName{
        Integer getId();
        String getTask();
    }
```

I am accessing the projection in my repository like this.

```java
@Query("select task from ToDoList task")
List<TaskIdAndName> getTaskIdAndName();
```

This is working fine and I am getting a list of objects with IDs and tasks like this.

```json
[
    {"id":1,"task":"Buy Groceries"},
    {"id":2,"task":"Clean the room"}
]
```

Although I am wondering is there any way I could add a custom field to each of the objects? Let us say I want to add a custom message to each object like this.

```json
[
    {"id": 1, "task": "Buy Groceries", "message": "This is a custom message"},
    {"id": 2, "task": "Clean the room", "message": "This is a custom message"}
]
```

**Note**: This custom field does not belong to the entity.

Comment: Is the custom message same for all tasks?

Comment: Yes it is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add default method to your interface to return custom message as shown in below example:

```
interface TaskIdAndName{
    Integer getId();
    String getTask();
    default String getMessage() {
        return "This is a custom message";
    }
}
```

I have tested this approach on my machine and its working as expected.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I wanted.